# How to tokenize a string with an embedded string?

Tags: regex, haskell, lexical-analysis, alex

I am learning how to use the Haskell lexical analyzer tool called [Alex](http://www.haskell.org/alex/doc/html/introduction.html)<sup>1</sup>.

I am trying to implement a lexical analyzer for this string (an email "From:" header):

```
From: "John Doe" <john@doe.org>
```

I want to break it up into this list of tokens:

```
[
  From,
  DisplayName "John Doe",
  Email,
  LocalName "john",
  Domain "doe.org"
]
```

Below is my implementation. It works fine if the string doesn't contain a display name. That is, this works fine:

```
let s = "From: <john@doe.org>"
alexScanTokens s
```

However, when I include a display name, I get this error message:

```
[From*** Exception: lexical error
```

That is, this results in an error:

```
let s = "From: \"John Doe\" <john@doe.org>"
alexScanTokens s
```

I am guessing that this part of my `Alex` program is causing the error:

```
\"[a-zA-Z ]+\"      { \s -> DisplayName (init (tail s)) }
```

In `Alex` the left side is a regular expression:

```
\"[a-zA-Z ]+\"
```

and the right side is the action to be taken when a string is found that matches the regular expression:

```
{ \s -> DisplayName (init (tail s)) }
```

Any ideas on what the problem might be?

### Here is my lexical analyzer program:

```
{
module Main (main) where
}

%wrapper "basic"

$digit = 0-9            -- digits
$alpha = [a-zA-Z]       -- alphabetic characters

tokens :-

  $white+                    ;
  From:                     { \s -> From }
  \"[a-zA-Z ]+\"            { \s -> DisplayName (init (tail s)) }
  \<                        { \s -> Email }
  [$alpha]+@                 { \s -> LocalPart (init s) }
  [$alpha\.]+>               { \s -> Domain (init s) }

{
-- Each action has type :: String -> Token

-- The token type:
data Token =
    From                               |
    DisplayName String                 |
    Email                              |
    LocalPart String                   |
    Domain String       
    deriving (Eq,Show)

main = do
  s <- getContents
  print (alexScanTokens s)
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The "Alex" lexical analyzer tool may be found at this URL: http://www.haskell.org/alex/doc/html/introduction.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the space in `"John Doe"` that's causing trouble.

[Whitespace is ignored in character sets](http://www.haskell.org/alex/doc/html/charsets.html) like `[a-zA-Z ]`. To include the space, you need to escape it with a backslash, e.g. `[a-zA-Z\ ]`.

<sub>Also, I can't help but note that a lexer might be the wrong tool for this job. Consider writing a proper parser using e.g. [Parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec).</sub>